# How can I stop parenthesis and brackets from changing linespacing in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put together a bit of code to add multiline xlabels to a plot. I've got it working for the most part, but there's an odd issue. Namely that I can't line up two text instances when one has a parenthesis in it, and the other doesn't. Here's what I'm getting:
[image: With parenthesis]

But when I take out the parenthesis, everything lines up perfectly:
[image: No parenthesis]

The code I'm using to place the text looks like this:

```
t = axis.get_xticklabels()[0]
transform = t.get_transform()
pos = transform.inverted().transform(t.get_window_extent())
if pos[0, 0] <= axis.get_xlim()[0]:
    right = 2*pos[0, 0]-axis.get_xlim()[0]
else:
    right = axis.get_xlim()[0]
top = pos[1, 1]
props = dict((p, getattr(t, 'get_' + p)()) for p in
     ['color', 'family', 'size', 'style', 'variant', 'weight'])
title = titles[0]
for t in titles[1:]:
    title = title + '\n' + t
return axis.text(right, top, title, transform=transform,
               ha='right', va='top', **props)
```

How can I fix it so that the parenthesis don't mess it up?

Comment: you should post the code you're using to do this. Unless we know how you're doing the alignment it's going to to be hard to suggest improvements.

Comment: I would recommend changing the font to a fixed-width font. This will cause all characters to take up the same amount of space because even your "lined up" version isn't actually lined up.

Comment: @Suever Thanks for the suggestion. That solution does work, however, I want to distribute this function around my lab, and would prefer to have this work in the general case, if at all possible. (By the way, while it may not look lined up, I did a pixel analysis, and it is indeed lined up.)

Comment: @BossColo I'm not sure how using a fixed-width font isn't a general solution. If you look at the pixels with the parentheses, you will realize that they are also lined up. Also I was talking about the numeric labels lining up not just the titles.

Comment: @Suever If I distribute this, I'll have to advise everyone that they have to change the fonts on all of their plots. It would be nice if I could let them use it no-strings-attached. As for the columns not lining up, that shouldn't be an issue. Thanks for looking out though.

Comment: @BossColo As I said though, it *does* line up if you actually look closely.

Comment: @Suever I'm not sure what you mean. It does line up in the second one, my problem is with the first one. When there are parenthesis, it doesn't line up.